# How to ignore placeholder text in iOS6 UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, placeholder

I have a data entry app which I have developed primarily with iOS7 in focus but it will support ios 6. I noticed that when I am trying to check if a `UITextField` is empty when I try to validate a form in iOS6 it will tell me that it is not empty if there is a **placeholder text** there. In iOS 7 I don't have this problem.

Does anyone have any efficient solution for this except for matching every `UITextField's` content with its placeholdet text for all the `UITextFields` in the whole app?

**EDIT:** 
If the validation is the issue, here is my validation code. Very simply I iterate through an array with the mandatory `UITextFields` and check if there is any input in them.

```
-(void)checkIfComplete{
    BOOL complete = YES;
    for(int i = 0; i < self.mandatoryFields.count; i++){
        UITextField *tempTextField = self.mandatoryFields[i];

        if([tempTextField.text  isEqual: @""]){
            complete = NO;
        }
    }

    if(complete){
        self.btnSave.enabled = YES;
    }else{
        self.btnSave.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Okey this is very weird. When I load the `ViewController` with the `UITextFields` the validation is wrong (it says the form is complete even though it is not). But if I enter a `UITextField`, write something and then delete what I just wrote the validation is correct (it says the form is incomplete when it is). I am setting my placeholders from the Storyboard if that makes any difference.

Thank you

Comment: Post your relevant code. There is no way that a text field's `placeholder` would interfere with its `text` value. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, have updated

Comment: You don't explain what the issue is with the posted code. Are there fields that appear empty but the check fails? Perhaps they have a space in them or other whitespace. Use the debugger and run through this code and see what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
-(void)checkIfComplete{
    BOOL complete = YES;
    for(int i = 0; i < self.mandatoryFields.count; i++){
        UITextField *tempTextField = self.mandatoryFields[i];

        if(tempTextField.text.length == 0){
            complete = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    self.btnSave.enabled = complete;
}
```

Comment: The only real difference between this code and the OP's original code is that this code handles the case of a text field's `text` value being `nil`. And it seems that is an important difference in this case.